# Out of memory while using sed with multiline expressions on giant file

Tags: sed, large-files, out-of-memory

I am currently trying to remove all newlines that are not preceded by a closing parenthesis, so I came up with this expression:

```
sed -r -i -e ":a;N;$!ba;s/([^\)])\n/\1/g;d" reallyBigFile.log
```

It does the job on smaller files, but on this large file I am using (`3GB`), it works for a while then returns with an out of memory error:

```
sed: Couldn't re-allocate memory
```

Is there any way I could do this job without running into this issue. Using `sed` itself is not mandatory, I just want to get it done.

Comment: Use split to create more files out of the big one, then recompose it with cat.

Comment: There are many instances where i dont have a ending parentheses, if I split, probably I will not solve all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first three commands are the culprit:

```
:a
N
$!ba
```

This reads the entire file into memory at once. The following script should only keep one segment in memory at a time:

```
% cat test.sed
#!/usr/bin/sed -nf

# Append this line to the hold space. 
# To avoid an extra newline at the start, replace instead of append.
1h
1!H

# If we find a paren at the end...
/)$/{
    # Bring the hold space into the pattern space
    g
    # Remove the newlines
    s/\n//g 
    # Print what we have
    p
    # Delete the hold space
    s/.*//
    h
}
% cat test.in
a
b
c()
d()
e
fghi
j()
% ./test.sed test.in
abc()
d()
efghij()
```

This awk solution will print each line as it comes, so it will only have a single line in memory at a time:

```
% awk '/)$/{print;nl=1;next}{printf "%s",$0;nl=0}END{if(!nl)print ""}' test.in
abc()
d()
efghij()
```

Comment: It just prints abc() and stops?

Comment: I have just checked and it does not stop. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, a Perl solution: `perl -p -e '/)$/ || chomp'`

For symmetry: `-p` wraps your script in a loop reading and printing line by line; the `-e` expression/script matches `)` at the end of the line, if it doesn't match (match is false) it goes on to `chomp`, which removes the newline at the end.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
sed -i -z -u 's/\n/ /g' reallyBigFile.log
```

-z, --null-data
separate lines by NUL characters

-u, --unbuffered
load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush the output buffers more often